# Renaming the volume or folder in which the Aperture library resides

Tags: macos, finder, aperture

When you rename or move folders or volumes on a Mac, do applications know the files moved.

Specifically, I have an external drive with a name, say "A very long long name", and I want to rename the drive to "Short-Name"

And inside that Drive, I have a folder with a long name which I want to rename to a shorter name.

Aperture is referencing these paths in a very large library (>100,000 images)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Aperture will continue to look in the old location until you tell it differently. To do this:

1. Quit Aperture before changing the volume/folder names.
2. Make your changes in Finder.
3. Reopen Aperture and go to Aperture > Preferences.
4. Click General, if necessary.
5. Under the Library Location option, click Choose.
6. Locate your library and click Select.
7. Quit Aperture and restart it.